# ios map snap to road implementation

Tags: ios, algorithm, google-maps, mapkit, openstreetmap

I'm indie IOS developer, trying to build in app turn by turn navigation.
now i'm using google maps , and google direction service for routes

***the problem:*** user location is out of the road most of the time, because of GPS accuracy limitation. I tried to implement 'snap to road: map matching' with no success. I didn't figure out the algorithm

where should i begin, should i use mapkit instead of google maps? openstreetmap?

could you please give me link to snap to road algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Apple has MKDirectionRequest through which you can get route polyline. to get the polyline you can pass the source, destination. but I see that you are using a GPS device so there may be lots of way points and the user may navigate through any possible path. so you can get direction for each point and plot the route for each lat/long combination on map. but its little slower performance also apple won't allow you to make multiple calls (I noticed >50/sec may fail). I am still researching whether apple has snap to roads api similar like google.

Both apple and googles direction request won't give 100% result what the user expects from the GPS lat/long.

from my research I found Snap to road API gives closer path to GPS trails. but there are some routes which goes out of road. I hope google may improve the accuracy in future. Also I hope market will provide snap to road API in future versions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

Using road inspector you can inspect the lat/long trails, whether the snap to road properly snaps to road:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/inspector

Check the above URL.

it has a javascript example request and parsing code.

Request Example:
  https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907|-35.28099,149.12929|-35.28144,149.12984|-35.28194,149.13003|-35.28282,149.12956|-35.28302,149.12881|-35.28473,149.12836&interpolate=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
Response:
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2784167,
        "longitude": 149.1294692
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280321693840129,
        "longitude": 149.12908274880189
      },
      "originalIndex": 1,
      "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2803415,
        "longitude": 149.1290788
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2803415,
        "longitude": 149.1290788
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280451499999991,
        "longitude": 149.1290784
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2805167,
        "longitude": 149.1290879
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2805901,
        "longitude": 149.1291104
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2805901,
        "longitude": 149.1291104
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280734599999995,
        "longitude": 149.1291517
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2807852,
        "longitude": 149.1291716
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2808499,
        "longitude": 149.1292099
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280923099999995,
        "longitude": 149.129278
      },
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280960897210818,
        "longitude": 149.1293250692261
      },
      "originalIndex": 2,
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    ... results truncated ...
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.284728724835304,
        "longitude": 149.12835061713685
      },
      "originalIndex": 7,
      "placeId": "ChIJW5JAZmpNFmsRegG0-Jc80sM"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the how inaccurate is GPS. What is the error in Positioning?.
Calculate the maximum error in as many no of tests you can do. Then evaluate the closest road in the radius of maximum error.

**Note:-** This guess might go wrong with some low probability.

Comment: Such approach is too naive, it is not uncommon they you have very close "roads" next to each other and by some fraction the one ("incorrect" one) is closer to the track. If anything there has to be added stability factor -- i.e. which road was used previously and if it possible at all to change roads at arbitrary point.